# Overloading + operator in python with a function writen in C++

Tags: python, c++, extending

is it possible to Overload pythons + operator using the Python C API.

for example if i run this code in python:

```
C = A+B
```

id like to be able to call this function written in c++

```
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator+(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
  for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
    result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] + rhs(i,j);
  }
}

return result;}
```

is doing this possible?

Comment: This is exactly what `numpy` does.  Note that you can't override integers this way; `A`, `B`, and `C` would have to be members of a class that is implemented in your C++ code.

Comment: so i only overload numpy Arrays?

Comment: yes so i create the matrices using my class

Comment: Why would you do this, since `numpy` already has highly optimized matrix manipulation abilities?  It is possible, but I don't see the point.  There are tutorials on how to create C++ modules callable from Python.  If you have `boost`, it's not that hard.

Comment: Yeah I have a project and one of the requirements is wrapping from scratch. Also I tried install boost and it works but I keeps saying it cannot find pyconfig.h when I build

Comment: Is this on Linux?  You need the `python-dev` (possibly `python3-dev` package.